# SharePoint 2013 Web part page title when homepage

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am working with a SharePoint 2013 site with no custom branding. When I change the home page of the site to a web part page, the page title changes to the site title. Is there a way to change that so that even though a page is the home page, it still shows the page title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding this to the page to override the title:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    Page Title
</asp:Content>
```